# Changing links from external source

Tags: jquery

I have a script that creates some content on a webpage. The script also creates a link and I would like to add  `target="_parent"` to this link. My question is if there is any possibility of manipulating the

`<a href="https://example.com">sometext</a>`

into

`<a target="_parent" href="https://example.com">sometext</a>`

even if IK cannot change the script itself. e.g. by jQuery append or a similar technique after the page loaded completely.

Comment: So why are you not adding it when you create the link???

Comment: Select the link and add the target.  If the url is known you can target the href attribute in the selector.

Comment: Sure, but you haven't said what the selection criteria would be. Adding an attribute to an element is trivial, but I'm sure you don't want to modify every anchor on the page.

Comment: Now, maybe I described the problem not correctely. The content is delivered from an external page. I just pasted the <script> and the script creates the content. That explains why I cannot modify the link directly. My only possibility is to add the target with some jQuery. I hope I explained now better.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with some javascript.

Vanilla - setAttribute()

```js
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
link.setAttribute("target", "_parent");
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com">sometext</a>
```

jQuery - attr()

```js
$('a:first').attr('target', '_parent');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://example.com">sometext</a>
```